# Query mysql in multi thread/process

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, multiprocessing, mysql-python

1.I know it will occur the error when connection is shared between threads.what about multi processing?

without db.commit(),the error will occur when events start by thread,but process will not.why?

aren't they shared the same connection from `db = sql.connect(ipAddress,db='mydb')`?

with db.commit(),both thread and process motheds will occur the error when sharing connection.

```
db = sql.connect(ipAddress,db='mydb')
def query():
    ii = 0
    while 1:
        cur = db.cursor(sql.cursors.Cursor)
        try:
            ii += 1
            s = 'ii:{}'.format(ii)
            cur.execute('''update test set count='{}' where name = 'sean' ''' .format(s))
            db.commit()
            cur.execute('''select count from test ''')
            rcv = cur.fetchall()
            print(cur,rcv)

        except (sql.Error,sql.Warning) as e:
            print(e)

        cur.close()
        time.sleep(1)

def getdb():
    while 1:
        cur1 = db.cursor(sql.cursors.Cursor)
        try:
            cur1.execute('''select count from test where name ='sean' ''')
            rcv = cur1.fetchall()
            print(cur1,rcv)

        except (sql.Error,sql.Warning) as e:
            print(e)

        cur1.close()
        time.sleep(1)

event = mp.Process(target = query)
event.start()
time.sleep(3)

event = mp.Process(target = getdb)
event.start()
```

2.I create two connections for each thread or process.
I don't know why I got the latest value `ii` only at first time when both connections access the same database.How could this be happened?

```
db = sql.connect(ipAddress,db='mydb')
db1 = sql.connect(ipAddress,db='mydb')
def query():
    ii = 0
    while 1:
        cur = db.cursor(sql.cursors.Cursor)
#        same code given above

def getdb():
    while 1:
        cur1 = db1.cursor(sql.cursors.Cursor)
#        same code given above
```

```
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3ef0> (('ii:50',), ('!999!',), ('$5555555555$',))
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3ef0> (('ii:3',),)
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3ed0> (('ii:51',), ('!999!',), ('$5555555555$',))
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3e50> (('ii:3',),)
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3e90> (('ii:52',), ('!999!',), ('$5555555555$',))
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x75ff3f70> (('ii:3',),)
<MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x766cb0b0> (('ii:53',), ('!999!',), ('$5555555555$',))
```

Comment: Every process is its own instance of the program and will have its own connection(s).

Comment: @Klaus D,But their cursors created from the same connection.It means they share the same connection.Doesn't it?